# how to return exact error from create params if any missing

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have following create params that are passed to create!

```
  def create_params
    params.permit(
      :param1,
      :param2,
      :param3,
      :param4,
      :param5
    )
  end
```

Controller

```
  def create
    something = Model.create!(create_params)
  end
```

All the columns in the table are NOT NULL. So if i not pass any one of the param i get error something like below

```
Mysql2::Error: Field 'col5' doesn't have a default value: INSERT INTO `table` (`col1`, `col2`, `col3`, `col4`) VALUES ('value1', 'value2, 'value3', 'value4')
```

But its not giving the exact error message. How can i have it return some valid error message?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having validations at database level like `NOT NULL` is a good practice.
But it is not possible, or reliable, to catch an error raised by the DB.
If you want good error messages, do the validation at ActiveRecord's level.

```
class Model < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :param1, :param2, :param3, :param4, :param5, presence: true
end

class ModelsController < ApplicationController
  def create
    model = Model.new(create_params)

    if model.save # returns true or false
      # ... do something
    else
      # ... model.errors is a collection that holds errors
      model.errors
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: `Model.create` will try to create a record in the database.    Better way to do it is by `model = Model.new(create_params)`. Then `model.save` makes sense.

Comment: so if i add that validates check in model and if i add update action in controller along with create and for update all params are not necessary then would that still work?

Comment: @Nicholasjames yes, this is possible: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#on